# How to pass a query string value to a page loaded via AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I am trying to put a variable into an AJAX-loaded page link I can call it on the content it loads?

I have tried:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxpage('/content/staff/profile.php?nav={$array['username']}', 'content')">
        <?php
            $i++;
            echo "<div style=\"float:left; width:{$row_width}%;text-align:center;\">\n";
            echo "<i>&raquo;{$array['username']}</i>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
            echo "</a><br />\n";
```

I tried putting the link inside and outside the php code but neither of them worked, I also tried a few differents ways of calling it including `$array['username']` All I need is a way I can define the variable "nav" as username (which is set in a database) so I can use it on that content that is called by the link.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I can't help with your query, I'm afraid, but if I were you, I'd try to format your code in such a way that people can read it easily without a scrollbar. Good luck! I hope you get a satifactory answer in not too long.

Comment: The code is actually allot longer then what you can actually see and in its original source it is that long so that everything inside a div is shown so that it can be easily seen that it is inside that div (rather then scrolling through allot of code looking for what is causing a problem).

Comment: I take this is a page loaded via AJAX. What do you mean by "so I can call it on the content it loads"?

Comment: When the link is clicked it will use AJAX to load a page called profile.php, this page will want to use the information stored in the variable 'nav' sent through (in) the link itself (or whatever method will work) and then use it to do other tasks.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Is the username defined by the session? If so, you should use the session rather than passing a username, otherwise people will be able to pass whatever username they like to access other people's pages.

Comment: No, it is not login, it must

Comment: It calls all the users from the table (in the database (that meet a certain requirement)) (this has already been done an is working) and lists them, but the list alone will not help much as they all need links and they all need the username that they are listed as in the link, this is an attempt to make staff profile pages that are viewable by everyone, it needs to define the variable 'nav' from the information in the database and then allow the page 'profile' to call it so that it can use it in its own database query and display information specific to the user selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understood your question.

But perhaps you want to try this out:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ajaxpage('/content/staff/profile.php?nav=<?php echo $array['username'];?>', 'content')">
    <?php
                            $i++;
                            echo "<div style=\"float:left; width:{$row_width}%;text-align:center;\">\n";
                            echo "<i>&raquo;", $array['username'], "</i>\n";
                            echo "</div>\n";
                            echo "</a><br />\n";
```

Comment: I am attempting to make a page for every user in a database (using my current template) so I need it to send the value 'nav' which will contain the selected username (called by {$array['username']) but no matter what I do I can not make it so the username can be read while in the link (the second time it is called it displays the username without problem).

Comment: (The page does not reload or load into a new page it will only be loading the page called "profile.php" into the content area)

Comment: then i suppose my code could work, you must use <?php tags outside to print variables.

Comment: Yes, but the original way I tried it was having it all in php but I found wherever it had / in the link it was ignored so I had to move it out, also if it is put inside <?php tags in the HTML tag then it does not display it, I think what I need is some way to close the HTML halfway so I can open php, then reopen the HTML where it was left off.

Comment: I looked over the code and found some typos, fixed them up and, tried again and found this solution (after I fixed the typos I made) worked, thank you for your help :).